# How to access a button not originally on page to animate and refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this codepen to practice working with APIs and search bar animations.

[wikiSearch codepen](https://codepen.io/jdagley77/pen/awPzwg/)

```
  <form class="form">
<input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-search fa fa-search" id="submit"></button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-reset fa fa-times" id="reset" onclick="moveReset();"></button>
```

some of my js

```
$('.btn-reset').on('click', function(){
    $('.btn-reset').css({
      'right': '22px'
    })
    $('.btn-search').css({
  'background-color': 'white'
    })
})
```

How can I access the X button after the search results come in?

On the splash page, the X button works as I want it to - moves right when input is focused and moves back to the left where it is hidden.

My goal is to have this behavior persist, even after the results display, and in addition to refresh to the original splash page.

I've tried adding an active class when it is clicked,delegating to #reset from body, adding an onclick event inline with the html, and using the location reset property, to no avail.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You have a z-index management problem. After click on search button the reset button has a z-index value of -1, this means that even you are see the button when you think you click on it you don't.

A way to fix this particular problem could be to remove the z-index attribute in your css file for reset button, also give z-index value to input control like 5 and for the search button like 10 to keep the logic you already have.

```js
// form validation
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    var word =  $("#search").val();
    if (word.length === 0) {
      alert("This field is required"); 
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('form').css({
        "margin-top": "0%"
      })
      $('body').css("background", "yellow")
      search(word);
    } 
})
  
// retrieve data from wikipedia api
function search(word) {
  $.ajax({
     url: '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
     data: { 
      action: 'opensearch', 
      list: 'search', 
      search: word, 
      format: 'json'
    },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     
     success: function (response) {
      var content = ''
      
      for (var i = 0; i < response[1].length; i++) {
          content += 
          '<div class="item"> <a class="item-text" target="_blank" href='+response[3][i]+">"
              +"<h3>"+response[1][i]+"</h3>" 
              +"<p>" + response[2][i] + "</p>"
          +'</a> </div>';
       };
        
          $('#content').html(content)
          .css({
              "margin": "5% 25%",  
              "text-align": "center"
           });  
        }
    });
}


$('input').on('focus', function(){
  $('.btn-reset').css({
    'right': '-22px',
    'background-color': 'white'
  })
  $('.btn-search').css({
    'background-color': 'hotpink'
  })
})


$('.btn-reset').on('click', function(){
  $('.btn-reset').css({
    'right': '22px'
  })
  $('.btn-search').css({
    'background-color': 'white'
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: Chartreuse ;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

/* search button: */

input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  z-index:5;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    text-align: center;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-search {
    background: hotpink;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:10;
}

.btn-reset {
    background: hotpink;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
}

form {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0% 27%;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  width: 50%;
}

input:focus {
   width: 100%;
}

.btn-search {
    background: hotpink;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-reset:focus {
    right: -22px;
}

button {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-search {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 26px;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 26px;
 }

.btn-reset {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 20px;    
 }



h3 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* for underlining each item block */
/* .item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 12.5%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
} */

.item-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#returned {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class='search-wrapper'>
  <form class="form">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search fa fa-search" id="submit"></button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-reset fa fa-times" id="reset"></button>
  </form>
</div>
    <br>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm getting you, you're looking for how to cause certain effects on the reset button when certain events happen? If I'm getting that, then there are really two events: first, any time the text input loses focus (at which point, you'd hide the reset button, I assume), and second, when the reset button itself is clicked.

Looking at the first case, you'd simply have the on('blur', function(){...}) set on the input, just as you have on('focus', function(){...}) happening right now. When the input is blurred, simply re-hide the reset and toggle the color change back on the search button.

In the second case, you're missing a line to actually clear the contents of the input. Presumably, you'd also want to remove the results of any search if you clear the input, but that's not really a given.

Hope this helps, if not please clarify!

```js
// form validation
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    var word =  $("#search").val();
    if (word.length === 0) {
      alert("This field is required"); 
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('form').css({
        "margin-top": "0%"
      })
      $('body').addClass("body-with-results");
      search(word);
    } 
})
  
// retrieve data from wikipedia api
function search(word) {
  $.ajax({
     url: '//en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
     data: { 
      action: 'opensearch', 
      list: 'search', 
      search: word, 
      format: 'json'
    },
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     
     success: function (response) {
      var content = ''
      
      for (var i = 0; i < response[1].length; i++) {
          content += 
          '<div class="item"> <a class="item-text" target="_blank" href='+response[3][i]+">"
              +"<h3>"+response[1][i]+"</h3>" 
              +"<p>" + response[2][i] + "</p>"
          +'</a> </div>';
       };
        
          $('#content').html(content)
          .css({
              "margin": "5% 25%",  
              "text-align": "center"
           });  
        }
    });
}


$('#search').on('focus', function(){
  $('.btn-reset').show();
  $('.btn-search').css({
    'background-color': 'hotpink'
  })
}).on('blur', function(){
  $('.btn-search').css({
    'background-color': '#ccc'
  });
})


$('#resetBtn').on('click', function(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $('#content').empty();
  $('#search').val('');
  $("body").removeClass("body-with-results");

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: Chartreuse ;
}

.body-with-results {
  background: yellow;
}
/* search button: */

input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
}

button {
    text-align: center;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.btn-search {
    background: hotpink;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#resetBtn {
    display: none;
    background: white;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -28px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
}

form {
  float: left;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0% 27%;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

input {
  border-radius: 15px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  width: 50%;
}

input:focus {
   width: 100%;
}

.btn-search {
    background: hotpink;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-reset:focus {
    right: -22px;
}

button {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-search {
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 26px;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 26px;
 }

.btn-reset {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: -1;
 }



h3 {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


.item {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/* for underlining each item block */
/* .item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 75%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 12.5%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
} */

.item-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#returned {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='search-wrapper'>
  <form class="form">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search fa fa-search" id="submit"></button>
    <button class="btn btn-reset fa fa-times" id="resetBtn"></button>
  </form>
</div>
    <br>
<div id="content">




</div>
```

A few changes have been made to the code. Specifically, what's happening is when the form has been submitted and the body's CSS altered, there is a z-index issue cropping up. Here are the changes made:

1. The body el style is now being changed by adding/removing a 'body-with-results" class. This is purely cosmetic, as I really don't like hard-coding style changes.
2. The reset button is no longer a pure reset button, it is now simply a styled button that simulates a reset. When you reset a form, that's all you reset. However, in this case, you want to reset the form, hide the reset element, and clear any results from the contents div. So the reset el now does just that.
3. Styles on the reset button -- rather than sliding in and out (which could still probably be a thing), I simply set the right/top values in the css, and also fixed the z-index thing. Note that I used the ID of the el rather than the class to set the styles. This was done to properly handle the specificity of the styles (IDs are considered more specific than classes, thus ID styles override class styles).
4. I removed the code to hide the reset button on blur -- the issue with that becomes, when you try to click on the reset button, the first event is the input blur, which promptly hides the element you just thought you clicked on.

Still trying to track down the wierd suggested results remnant code, but this is a starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Snowmonkey, this gets me part of the way there. The blur event was what I was looking for. The issue I'm still running into is $('#content').val('') doesn't clear the content as expected, and $('#search').val('') doesn't clear the search field once the results appear (it does work before you submit though). An unrelated, bonus question is when the input bar floats to the top of the page after i search, the search history suggestions stick to the page where they were initially, and don't move with the rest of the search form.

Comment: And $('#content').val('') wouldn't, in fact, clear the div -- .val() is for input elements. You'd want to use $("#content").empty() or $("#content").text(" ") to clear it out.